# Error changing edge thickness in a GraphPlot

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, warning-messages, version-7

I'm having some problems with the *Mathematica* graphics inspector. I want to make a graph with the following  code:

```
GraphPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
    DirectedEdges -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> True, SelfLoopStyle -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which results in a good looking graph. But when I use Graphics Inspector to alter the weight of the edges, it gives me an error and *Mathematica* closes. Does anyone else have ever experienced this? Or do you have another solution for me to achieve my graph with weighted edges?

I'm using *Mathematica* version 7.

Comment: There were several syntax errors in your code which I corrected. How could this ever have produce a working graph? And what do you mean with "Graphics Inspector"? Do you mean the Drawing Tools palette? I don't have any problems changing line thickness using Win-7 Mathematica version 8.04 and the palette.

Comment: I'm sorry for not using the brackets, i couldn't just copy paste my code since it crashed. If you right click on the picture you can select graphics inspector and with graphics inspector you can change the line thickness but in my  case it crashed. I got a runtime error and the error log said that {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,1} is not an exspected array6

Comment: I've been using v8 for too long, but from the mists of my memory I seem to remember that in v7 it used to be called a Graphics Inspector indeed.

Comment: You could try `EdgeRenderingFunction` to programmetically set edge thickness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `EdgeRenderingFunction` to set edge thickness:

```
GraphPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> True, SelfLoopStyle -> True,
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Darker[Red], Thickness[0.01], 
     Arrow[#1, .05]} &)]
```

[image: thick graph]

Comment: I don't think you should mark this and the other answer as community wiki.

Comment: These are questions whose answer is already in the comments. I was  randomly going through them and abiding to [these guidelines](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/916/unanswered-questions-guidelines-proposal)

Comment: Ah, yes, well I do not agree with this policy :) I think it is wrong habit to put answers in comments. Also, I think one should be rewarded for putting his effort in creating and answer with valid code.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly like they're flooding with upvotes so neither me nor whoever posted the answer in the comments is missing out on reputation. It's just that there's about a thousand of these and my guess (from whatever limited archaeology I have done) is that there must be at least a third that are answered in the comments and nobody bothered since.

Comment: By reward I do not mean +15, +1 is reasonable for helping tiding this site :). They may not be popular but they are not closed, so they can be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

`GraphPlot` also accepts `Plot` options. So, you can use `BaseStyle->Thick` or `PlotStyle-Thick`:

```
GraphPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    DirectedEdges -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> True, SelfLoopStyle -> True]
```

[image]

```
GraphPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[Table[.05, {5}]]],
  DirectedEdges -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> True, SelfLoopStyle -> True]
```

[image]